# Named non-capturing group in python?

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to have named non-capturing group in python? For example I want to match string in this pattern (including the quotes):

"a=b"
'bird=angel'

I can do the following:

```
s = '"bird=angel"'
myre = re.compile(r'(?P<quote>[\'"])(\w+)=(\w+)(?P=quote)')
m = myre.search(s)
m.groups()
# ('"', 'bird', 'angel')
```

The result captures the quote group, which is not desirable here.

Comment: Why not just ignore that particular capture group once you get your matches?

Comment: In case there are many more named groups that need to be ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do *need* a capturing group in order to match the *same* quote: there is no other mechanism in `re` that allows you to do this, short of explicitly distinguishing the two quotes:

```
myre = re.compile('"{0}"' "|'{0}'" .format('(\w+)=(\w+)'))
```

(which has the downside of giving you *four* groups, two for each style of quotes).

Note that one does not need to give a name to the quotes, though:

```
myre = re.compile(r'([\'"])(\w+)=(\w+)\1')
```

works as well.

In conclusion, you are better off using `groups()[1:]` in order to get only what you need, if at all possible.

Answer (score 11):

No, named groups are *always* capturing groups. From the documentation of the `re` module:

> Extensions usually do not create a new group; **`(?P<name>...)` is the
>   only exception to this rule.**

And regarding the named group extension:

> Similar to **regular parentheses**, but the substring matched by the group
>   is accessible within the rest of the regular expression via the
>   symbolic group name name

Where `regular parentheses` means `(...)`, in contrast with `(?:...)`.